# Uploading videos to office 365 video channel through Powerapp

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am new to Powerapp. I am trying to make a Powerapp through which i can upload the videos to Office 365 Video channel. How can do it.? I am not even able to get any of the similar kind of article. Thank you!